# Unity flying smooth rotation broke rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I realized that the turning for my jet game isnt smooth, as it just flat out rotates. I am now trying to use angular velocity, so I can just curve it so it stops rotation smoothly, but it will no longer turn. Any Idea why? The old code is what is commented out in the maneuver void.

I tried to change the code, but it isnt working. Any ideas why? I honestly have no clue why it wont work anymore.

Would It be better to instead make a small block of code that will smoothen out the amount of degrees rotated at once? Changing the values of PitchSpeed from 7 and curving it?

```
    public float MaxSpeed;
    public float StallSpeed;
    public float Accelleration;
    public float Deccelleration;
    public float AfterburningSpeed;
    public float NormalSpeed;
    public float AirBrakeSpeed;
    public float CurrentSpeed;
    public float YawSpeed;
    public float PitchSpeed;
    public float RollSpeed;
    public float HGturnspeed;
    public float HGpenalty;
    public float MaxPitchVel;
    public float MaxRollVel;
    public float MaxYawVel;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public bool AirBraking;
    public bool HGing;
    public bool Afterburning;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            Afterburning = true;
        }else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            Afterburning = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            AirBraking = true;
        }else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            AirBraking = false;
        }
        if (CurrentSpeed > (NormalSpeed - 1) && CurrentSpeed < (NormalSpeed + 1) && Afterburning == false)
        {
            CurrentSpeed = NormalSpeed;

        }
        else if (CurrentSpeed < NormalSpeed && AirBraking == false && Afterburning == false)
        {
            CurrentSpeed += Accelleration;
        }
        else if (CurrentSpeed > NormalSpeed && Afterburning == false)
        {
            CurrentSpeed -= Deccelleration;
        }
        else if (AirBraking && CurrentSpeed >= StallSpeed)
        {
            CurrentSpeed -= AirBrakeSpeed;
        }
        else if (Afterburning && CurrentSpeed <= MaxSpeed)
        {
            CurrentSpeed += AfterburningSpeed;
        }
        if (CurrentSpeed > MaxSpeed )
        {
            CurrentSpeed = MaxSpeed;
        }else if (CurrentSpeed < StallSpeed)
        {
            CurrentSpeed = StallSpeed;
        }
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * CurrentSpeed;
        Manuvers();
        
        
    }
    void Manuvers()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && MaxPitchVel >= Mathf.Abs(rb.angularVelocity.x)) 
        {
            rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3((rb.angularVelocity.x - RollSpeed * Time.deltaTime), rb.angularVelocity.y, rb.angularVelocity.z);
          

            //transform.Rotate(((0 + (PitchSpeed * Time.deltaTime)) * 10), 0, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && MaxPitchVel >= Mathf.Abs(rb.angularVelocity.x))
        {
            rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3(rb.angularVelocity.x, (rb.angularVelocity.y + PitchSpeed * Time.deltaTime), rb.angularVelocity.z);
            // transform.Rotate((0 - ((PitchSpeed * Time.deltaTime))*10), 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && MaxRollVel >= Mathf.Abs(rb.angularVelocity.z))
        {
            rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3(rb.angularVelocity.x, rb.angularVelocity.y, (rb.angularVelocity.z - RollSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
            // transform.Rotate(0, 0, ((0 - (RollSpeed * Time.deltaTime))*10));
        }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && MaxRollVel >= Mathf.Abs(rb.angularVelocity.z))
        {
            rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3(rb.angularVelocity.x, rb.angularVelocity.y, (rb.angularVelocity.z + RollSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && MaxYawVel >= Mathf.Abs(rb.angularVelocity.y))
        {
            rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3(rb.angularVelocity.x, (rb.angularVelocity.y - PitchSpeed * Time.deltaTime), rb.angularVelocity.z);
            //  transform.Rotate(0, ((0 + (YawSpeed * Time.deltaTime)) * 10), 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q) && MaxYawVel >= Mathf.Abs(rb.angularVelocity.y))
        {
            rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3(rb.angularVelocity.x, (rb.angularVelocity.y + PitchSpeed * Time.deltaTime), rb.angularVelocity.z);
            //  transform.Rotate(0, ((0 - (YawSpeed * Time.deltaTime)) * 10), 0);
        }
    }
    public void HighGTurn()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z) && CurrentSpeed !<= (StallSpeed + 25))
        {
            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                HGing = false;
                return;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
               // transform.Rotate(((0 + (HGturnspeed * Time.deltaTime)) * 10), 0, 0);
                HGing = true;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
               // transform.Rotate(((0 - (HGturnspeed * Time.deltaTime)) * 10), 0, 0);
                HGing = true;
            }
        }
        if (HGing == true)
        {
            CurrentSpeed -= HGpenalty;
        }

        
    }    
}
```

Comment: @nontoxicguy rb is assigned, its public so gets assigned in editor By smooth rotation I mean adding falloff, so instead of stopping instantly like it used to, it would slow down instead. It was smooth during movement.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign rb because it's not assigned anywhere. Also, the Input class works in Update, not FixedUpdate. That's maybe why it wasn't smooth in the first place.